# Find which project in my solution has a reference to Framework 1.1

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My solutions contains lots of project (33), some vb, mostly c#. Now in one of those projects there is a reference to the 1.1 framework.
My solution builds successfully, but won't run. It gives me the error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.xml, Version=1.0.5000' or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified".

When I install the 1.1 framework it works just fine. I want to remove it so the 1.1 is not needed anymore to run my application.

How can I find where this reference is in all those projects? I know i've had to add in once to get a external lib working but now I stuck with the 1.1 framework...

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 2):

In your solution root, run this from the command-line:

```
findstr /I /S "1.0.5000" *.csproj
findstr /I /S "1.0.5000" *.vbproj
```

that will list all of the C# and VB.NET project files that contain references to any 1.0.5000-versioned assemblies.

Comment: +1 I have never come across findstr before. Of course, you can also do a Find in Files (Ctrl+Shift+F) in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried this but nothing found. After that I tried NeverHopeless his solution by checking every System.Xml reference in my 33 projects. All point to framework 4 and nothing to find that points to framework 1

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago, I faced the same issue and in order to resolve it these steps were followed:

In Solution Explorer:

1. Expand Project
2. Expand References
3. Select the DLL causing issue (In your case it would be `System.XML`)
4. Right Click and select `Properties`
5. Set `Specific Version` property to `False`

This should work in your case too!